# Save page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have a simple HTML page (XHTML 1.0 transitional),coded using CSS and Javascript.
This page contains a form. 
I want to save the HTML form including the values a user enters in the fields of the form.
I see that simply by using the 'save page as' option in firefox, I can save the html form with values, exactly as desired. 
But I want this to happen in Chrome and IE as well i.e, I want 'save page as' option to save values as well.
Currently, IE and chrome just save all the HTML, with no values.
If this is not possible using 'save page as' in IE and chrome, please suggest how to do this with javascript.
Coded example would be highly appreciated.
P.S., I want this HTML file to be portable, so that I can send it through e-mail, and whoever opens it, should see the field values already filled in.
Basically, I want this HTML/CSS/Javascript to be compatible with:

Chrome: Latest release
Firefox : Latest Release
IE: IE 8 to be used in windows XP

If not javascript, suggest some other method to do it.

 Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really doesn't sound like HTML is the ideal medium for what you're asking. Have you considered something like PDF forms or InfoPath?

Comment: I would like to stick to the usage of HTML for this. BTW, I was able to implement this in Firefox, and Chrome, using Javascript, by saving the values of fields into the value attribute itself for all the elements. But IE8 is still not able to save the values, just saving out HTML.